# I want a method to extract Values that may sometimes contain "& and =" from URL parameters in Java

Tags: java, url-parameters

```
package com.bml.icbs.ws.param;    
import java.util.HashMap;
```

public class RequestParameter {

```
private String param;
private HashMap<String, String> hashmap;

    public RequestParameter(String param){

    this.param=param;
    this.hashmap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    Integer i; 
    String key,value;
    String myArray[] = this.param.split("&");


    for (i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){

        key=myArray[i].substring(0,myArray[i].indexOf("="));
        value=myArray[i].substring(myArray[i].indexOf("=")+1);
        this.hashmap.put(key,value);
    }
}

public String getParameterValue(String key){
    return this.hashmap.get(key);
}

public String getParam() {
    return param;
}

public void setParam(String param) {
    this.param = param;
}

public HashMap<String, String> getHashmap() {
    return hashmap;
}

public void setHashmap(HashMap<String, String> hashmap) {

    this.hashmap = hashmap;
}
```

}

> When I Test the above method in case the URL is "param2=ffffhhh&param1=oooo&param3=pppp&param4=iiii&param5=kkkkk"

`The result is: 
SIZE 5
URL param2=ffffhhh&param1=oooo&param3=pppp&param4=iiii&param5=kkkkk
HASHMAP {param1=oooo, param2=ffffhhh, param3=pppp, param4=iiii, param5=kkkkk}
PARAM1 = oooo`

which is correct

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    RequestParameter reqParam = new RequestParameter("param2=ffffhhh&param1=oooo&param3=pppp&param4=iiii&param5=kkkkk");
    System.out.println("SIZE " + reqParam.getHashmap().size());
    System.out.println("URL " + reqParam.getParam());
    System.out.println("HASHMAP " + reqParam.getHashmap());
    System.out.println("PARAM1 = " reqParam.getParameterValue("param1"));

}
```

> but In case I pass the URL as the following one: 
>   "param2=ffff&&&hhh=&param1=oooo=&&param3=pppp&param4=iiii&&yy=&param5=kkkkk"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RequestParameter reqParam = new RequestParameter("param2=ffff&&&hhh=&param1=oooo=&&param3=pppp&param4=iiii&&yy=&param5=kkkkk");
    System.out.println("SIZE " + reqParam.getHashmap().size());
    System.out.println("URL " + reqParam.getParam());
    System.out.println("HASHMAP " + reqParam.getHashmap());
    System.out.println("PARAM1 = " reqParam.getParameterValue("param1"));

}
```

> 

it throws the following exception: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1937)
    at com.bml.icbs.ws.param.RequestParameter.(RequestParameter.java:188)
    at com.bml.icbs.ws.param.main.main(main.java:9)

Comment: This happens because you can´t create a substring of an empty String that is beeing split by the "&". For better understanding, print out the information in your loop after splitting by the "&", you will notice having empty strings a few times, because of the repeating "&" at the beginning.

Comment: @KevinEsche Thanks but do you have any solution?

Comment: just ignore the empty string by using continue when it´s empty or don´t do anything if it´s empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure array element !empy.

```
for (i=0;i<myArray.length;i++){
        if(myArray[i] == null || myArray[i].length()==0){
                continue;
        }
        key=myArray[i].substring(0,myArray[i].indexOf("="));
        value=myArray[i].substring(myArray[i].indexOf("=")+1);
        this.hashmap.put(key,value);
    }
```

Comment: @Aya i am Yazan not Kevin Esche :), anyway, the error was because of `&&` so thats why you got `yy=` if this helped you plz mark as answer

Comment: Thank you for your help, but the idea is that we are taking cases that a parameter value may contain "&" or "=", so I'm looking for a method to extract the values with their "&" or "=" your solution gave me the following answer: HASHMAP {hhh=, param1=oooo=, param2=ffff, param3=pppp, param4=iiii, param5=kkkkk, yy=} But thanks a lot anyway :) it removed the exception that was occurring before  @Yazan

Comment: Yeah Exactly it is intentional because we are taking cases that a url parameter value may contain "=" or "&"  and we should include them the way they are in the extracted value, my method only works in case there are no "=" or "&" in the values. By the way, are you Arab? maybe we could understand each other better if you don't mind giving me ur email address. Thank you :) @Yazan

Comment: Thank you I got it (Y) @Yazan